# Label and frame expansion on button click in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, ios4

I need to expand a frame and label on the click of a button in a section of a table view. Similarly, when the button is clicked again, the frame and label should restore to their original (compressed) state. This has to be done for all sections of the table view. If I click on the button of one section, it's expanding frames for all sections. But the label is expanded for all on that clicked section. Below is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{                   
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];

    if(section==0 || section==2)
    {                   
        static NSString *myIdentifier = @"tableCell";

        DUGSProjectTableCell *cell = (DUGSProjectTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
        cell.readMoreButton.tag=[indexPath section];

        [cell.readMoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        if (section==0) {

            cell.myLabel.text=@"On this festive season one of the leading real estate developers in NCR Delhi, is launching a new residential project ";
        }

        else if (section==2){
            cell.myLabel.text=@"Situated in hot & fast upcoming neighbourhood,Spread in 30 acres,Located in the heart of the city";
        }

        if(self.isHeightChanged)
        {                       
            if ([cell.readMoreButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Read More"]) {

                [cell.readMoreButton setTitle:@"Read Less" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                cell.readMoreButton.frame=CGRectMake(223, 90 , 66, 25) ;

                CGRect frame = cell.myLabel.frame;

                cell.myLabel.numberOfLines=0;
                cell.myLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                frame.size.height=100;
                cell.myLabel.frame=frame;

            }

            else if ([cell.readMoreButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Read Less"])
            {
                [cell.readMoreButton setTitle:@"Read More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                cell.readMoreButton.frame=CGRectMake(223, 70 , 66, 25) ;

                CGRect frame = cell.myLabel.frame;

                cell.myLabel.numberOfLines=0;
                cell.myLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

                frame.size.height=30;
                cell.myLabel.frame=frame;

            }
        }
        return  cell;
    }

    else if (section==1){

        static NSString *myIdentifier = @"unitCell";

        DUGSUnitPlanCell *cell = (DUGSUnitPlanCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];

        return cell;

    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Below is the code for the button click:

```
 (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    DUGSProjectTableCell *selectedCell = (DUGSProjectTableCell*)[[button superview] superview];
    if (selectedCell) {



        if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Read More"] ) {
            whichButton=@"M";
            NSLog(@"%@",whichButton);
        }

        else if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Read Less"]){
           whichButton=@"L";
            NSLog(@"%@",whichButton);

        }
        NSLog(@"%d",selectedCell.readMoreButton.tag);

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:selectedCell.readMoreButton.tag];
        selectedIndexPath=indexPath;
        NSLog(@"%@",selectedIndexPath);
        self.isHeightChanged=YES;
        [self.tableViewForPropertyOverview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }

}
```

Below is the code for expanding the frame:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath section]==1){
        return 60;
    }

    if (([indexPath section]==0)||([indexPath section]==2)) {

        if (selectedIndexPath!=NULL){
            return 120.0f;

        }

        else{
            return 60.0f;

    }}

}
```

The frame size is increased to 120 for all sections. Instead, it should do so for section 0 & 2 when buttons inside them are clicked. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you really don't have 3 sections but rather one section with 3 table view cells.

It seems that there is some misconception about sections and rows. You write:

> **I need to expand a frame and label on the click of a button in a section of a table view.**

This does not make sense. There are no UI Elements in a table view section. Rather, a section contains rows (cells) which in turn contain labels, etc. and it might display a section header. So you really want to expand the rows belonging to a section.

Your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` cannot return anything else but `60.0` if it is the second section. But mind you, this method does not return a "section height" but the height of a row. If all three spaces you see are expanded, they must be all in section 0.

Assuming that you need just one row per section you need to:

- return 3 in `numberOfSections`
- return 1 in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Finally, to check your button's text to determine which one it was is not good practice. You can `tag` the button with an integer and then check `[(UIButton*)sender tag]` in the handler. I see you are using a tag somewhere there, but it is not clear why you would need a string constant as well.

Comment: i want section 0 height to change when the read more button of section 0 is pressed and same for the section 2..thats all i want ... could you please help me on this .